# Fiber weave effect calculation for a PCB

Tags: signal-integrity, cadence, intel, ads, hyperlynx

How can I calculate the angle offset and maximum length?

[image: option]

Here is my stack-up:

[image: Stack up]

You can consider my signal to be routed in layer 3.

Please help in understanding the calculation and concept of it.

Comment: Are you sure that your application requires worrying about this level of detail? What software are your screenshots from?

Comment: @JRE, the angle offset likely refers to the angle between the trace and the fiberglass weave, which can be controlled by laying out the board at an angle to the panel (at the expense of using the material somewhat inefficiently). It's something you'd tell the fab to do, not something they'd tell you about. But I'm not familar with the software being used so I'm not sure exactly how the angle is specified.

Comment: screenshot is from cadence